# How to parse a simple arithmetic operation with regex in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I'm making home page using AngularJS and there is arithmetic function.

```
<div class="input-form">
  <input ng-model="value1" id="value1" type="number" />
  <input ng-model="value2" id="value2" type="number" />
  <input ng-model="value3" id="value3" type="number" />
  <input ng-model="value4" id="value4" type="number" />
  <input ng-model="value5" id="value5" type="number" />
</div>
<div class="equation-form">
  <input ng-model="equation" type="text" />
</div>
<button class="yellow" ng-click="calculate()">Calculation</button>
```

If user press "Calculation" button after input arithmetic equation to equation field, need to calculate result and send server.

Equation input like as `"1 + 2 - 3 * 4 + 5"`.

1,2,3,4,5 values means input value named as value1, value2, value3, value4, value5

Here is what I tried to achieve the calculation:

```
scope.calculate = function () {
  let equation = scope.equation.replace(/\s+/g, ''); // remove spaces
  
  if (!/^\d+(?:[+-]\d+)*$/.test(expression)) { //
    console.error('wrong equation');
    return;
  }

  let fieldIndexes = expression.split(/(?=[+-])/); // split expression
  if (fieldIndexes) {
    fieldIndexes.forEach(x => {
      // process calculation
    });
  }
}
```

Function is done in two steps:

First, split equation to [ 1, +2, -3, *4, 5 ].

Second, calculate splited equation.

But now, I've only split by "-", "+".
If user input `"1 + 2 - 3 + 4 - 5"`, current function split it to `"1", "+2", "-3", "+4", "-5"`.

How can I split string by "-", "+", "*", "/" symbol?

Any suggestions?

Comment: You'd be better off with an expression parser, either existing (like mathjs) or a simple hand-rolled one.

Comment: Is it not possible with regex? I just want string to split by "+, -, *, /". There is no complex operator such as (), ^, etc.

Comment: There is still the order of operations (and negative numbers). At the very least I'd split into the digits and the operators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I wrote something that does not use RegExp.

```
class Operation {
    constructor(data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    result(items = null) {

        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            items[i] = items[i].split(this.data.op);

            if (this.data.next) {
                items[i] = this.data.next.result(items[i]);
            }

            items[i] = items[i].reduce(this.data.reducer);
        }

        return items;
    }
}

function calculate(expr) {
    var mult = new Operation({ op: "*", next: null, reducer: (f, l) => { return parseInt(f) * parseInt(l) } });
    var div = new Operation({ op: "/", next: mult, reducer: (f, l) => { return parseInt(f) / parseInt(l) } });
    var sub = new Operation({ op: "-", next: div, reducer: (f, l) => { return parseInt(f) - parseInt(l) } });
    var add = new Operation({ op: "+", next: sub, reducer: (f, l) => { return parseInt(f) + parseInt(l) } });
    return add.result([expr.replace(/\s+/g, "")])[0];
}
```

You supply the calculate function with the arithmetic expression and it returns the result for you.
Each operation layer passes the operands - "items" - to the next higher order operation until it reaches the last one (which here is multiplication).

Example:
console.log(calculate("6 * 5 - 2"));

Adding brackets now should be simple.

Does that help?